# setting divs to the height of the browser window

Tags: html

I have 2 divs, one above the other, I want them both to be 100% width and height of the browser window whilst still maintaining their order in the document.

at the moment as you can see I have just added an inline style to give the box 500px height so they are visible.

the relevant code thus far can be found here:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/pY6dc/9/

I'm very new to this so you may need to explain things in seriously simple terms. I'm aware that I will probably require some form of javascript in order to achieve this don't know where to even begin.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it in JavaScript:

```
$(".slide").height($(window).height());
```

What it does is select all elements with a class of slide, and then it sets their height to the windows height.

Updated fiddle: [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/pY6dc/12/)

But basically I am assuming you can hook up jQuery on your own, once you do that you can register a window load function in a lot of ways, simplest way is in a script tag (more appropriate way is in the head of your document).

---

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(window).load(function(){
      $(".slide").height($(window).height());
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Quick response but as mentioned I'm really new to this, where would this sit and how would it connect to the mark-up?

Comment: No worries, got it, still coming to terms with many of the basics, thanks a lot!